# YUV to h263/h264 compression on android to stream video

Tags: android, video-streaming, video-encoding, android-camera

I am trying stream video from android to network an receiving it on a server that I had written in c#.

I am capturing YUV data on `onPreviewFrame` method on Camera and sending it to the server where I convert this data to image and displaying it.

Everything works fine but the problem is that there is a lot much delay in the streaming process as I am sending the data directly. Is there some way of encoding this YUV data to h263 or h264(android 3.0+ only) format so that I can minimize the delay?

Also `MediaRecorder` have ability to record the video in the available standard video format but it stores the video to a file on sdcard. Is there any way of getting a stream from that video which is being recorded so that I can stream it to the network? This will reduce my efforts in conversion process.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out MediaCodec.
You still need a streaming container.